# Should I sell my remaining Rift Keystone fragments?

Tags: diablo-iii

Since the 2.3.0 patch, any rift keystones now have a message showing in the tooltip saying "This is useless. Perhaps you should sell it."

Given that they are no longer used to open the Nephalem rifts, is that indeed the case, or is there still some hidden use for them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not that I know of. The purpose for the devs to change the Obelisk to not use key stones for rifts was to change the dynamic between bounties and rifts. It's doubtful that these have anymore use, I've gotten rid of my own since they take up stash space.

Comment: Agreed, plus it is very nice profit for large stacks. That and I highly doubt they will be useful henceforth, being normally if Blizzard discontinues something it ( to my knowledge ) is never reused but may be replaced. My example is the Flint and tinder in World of Warcraft. I held onto 10 of them upto Cata then just decided to sell them off. Sell them now and make a profit or they may just disappear .